# How to set the screen bounds as a global CGRect for every function can access it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, global-variables, cgrect

I want to set UIScreen's bounds as a global `CGRect`. I set it as a `static const` but I get the error. I know the problem, screen's bounds isn't a compile-time constant. But I also want to set it as a global `CGRect`. What else can I do?

Code below:

```
static const CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds];
```

Error:

> Initializer element is not a compile-time constant

Comment: Why do you need the screen frame as a global? There is very little need to even know what the screen size is. If you think you need it you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use macro like this:

`#define SCREEN_BOUNDS [[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]`

Then you can call `SCREEN_BOUNDS` where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of setting a constant and accessing it anywhere is the fact that we can change the value of that constant and it's usage is not effected.
`[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]` is itself a constant. If you were to create a constant for that it would mean defining **a constant for a constant** (yes, it's value is different for different screen but iOS has provided the way to directly access it). My response would be to directly use `[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]` wherever necessary rather than creating a constant for that.